# Filtering out cases depending on multiple row conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I am currently working with parliamentary data. The rows are events that a bill went through. Below you can see exemplary data I created.
Now, I have to filter out all cases that contain a "Yes" twice. So in the example below, only bill "A" should remain. I thought about creating a helping df that summarises the number of grouped events, and I then filter out all Bills that display n=2. However, that seems not very elegant. How could I solve this problem?

```r
library(tidyverse)

bill <- c(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"),3))
event <-  c(rep("Yes",4),"No", rep("Yes",3), rep("Other",4))

data <- data.frame(bill, event)
data
#>    bill event
#> 1     A   Yes
#> 2     B   Yes
#> 3     C   Yes
#> 4     D   Yes
#> 5     A    No
#> 6     B   Yes
#> 7     C   Yes
#> 8     D   Yes
#> 9     A Other
#> 10    B Other
#> 11    C Other
#> 12    D Other

#wanted outcome
data %>%
  filter(bill== "A")
#>   bill event
#> 1    A   Yes
#> 2    A    No
#> 3    A Other
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After grouping by `bill` we could use `filter` to filter by the sum of event == "Yes" and not equal to 2:

```
library(dplyr) #dplyr >=1.1.0

data %>%
  filter(sum(event == "Yes") != 2, .by=bill)
```

OR

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(bill) %>%
  filter(sum(event == "Yes") != 2) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
 bill  event
  <chr> <chr>
1 A     Yes  
2 A     No   
3 A     Other
```